# Azure Web App (Linux) running old files compare to ACR artefact

Tags: azure, docker, web-applications, cicd, acr

WebApp is configured to fetch artefact from ACR as part of CI/CD.
The WebApp seems to be running old file compare to what the ACR artefact has (verified by pulling it down from ACR to localhost).

Have performed following actions:

1. Restarted WebApp
2. Re-constructed artefacts (by deleting them first).
3. Changed deployment centre settings and reverted back to original ones.
4. Opened the link in Private mode.
5. No caching options are set either.

Despite all the actions Web App is running an old file and when I SSH into the Web App file contents are old not what ACR artefact has.

Comment: There seems to be a compatibility issue with Azure WebApp supporting Docker Image `FROM node:18.14-alpine3.17`.

Please use `FROM node:18.13-alpine3.17`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Create a standard Dockerfile referring to image `FROM node:18.14-alpine3.17`.
Push the docker image to ACR and load the WebApp from ACR artefact an error message `Container ID 1516583083 cannot be mapped to a host IDErr: 0, Message: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): Container ID 1516583083 cannot be mapped to a host ID 2023-02-16T16:23:55.610Z INFO` will be thrown.

Comment: It appears neither of node version 19 https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/7abbf9f3d902b901da72714bcc30b5a92831547e/19/alpine3.16/Dockerfile can be used as a base image when deploying to Azure Web App containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a compatibility issue with Azure WebApp supporting Docker Image FROM node:18.14-alpine3.17. Please use FROM node:18.13-alpine3.17